# Having problem on setting window.localStorage keys as Object

Tags: javascript

I wanted to set object as a key of window.localStorage and set keys with increasing the value of the id by one. It works until it reaches 10 after that it won't increment to 11. It is really confusing me and have no hint to what the problem is.

```
<button id="addValue" onclick="addRecord()">Add</button>
<span id="currentId"></span>

<script>
  function addRecord() {
    let myDatabase = window.localStorage;
    let currentId = document.getElementById('currentId');
    let lastId = '';
    let fileId = {
      id: '',
    }
    let addedValues = {
      'fileNumber': 12,
      'volumeNumber': 1,
      'directorate': 'wana',
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < myDatabase.length; i++) {
      lastId = JSON.parse(myDatabase.key(i)).id;
    }
    try {
      fileId.id = ++lastId;
      currentId.innerHTML = fileId.id;
      myDatabase.setItem(JSON.stringify(fileId), JSON.stringify(addedValues));
    } catch (err) {
      alert(`There is some problem, the record cannot be saved! ${err}`);
    }
  }
</script>
```

The output should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ... but it stacks at 10

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yqtpo3sa/

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

The problem is with the storage.

you have to sort the keys at first after getting the records from `storage`.

when you store new `10th` records it get sorted and comes at `first index` of storage.

See here.

[image: See Image of Storage]

so you are getting the last item of the storage and last is always `9` because when `10th` added its move to the `0` index.

Comment: ok thanks, but why the problem occurs at ten what about 4, 5, 6?? doesn't window.localStorage stores data by Ascending order?

Comment: Its browser's default behaviour.

Comment: Therefore, should I sort always before adding new value

Comment: **when you store new 10th records it get sorted and comes at first index of storage.**  I was thinking about what you said and didn't gave me a sense. why everything starts at 10th record, what about 2, 3, 4 -9?

Comment: Great.
let myDatabase = window.localStorage;
you can use sorting after myDatabase to sort in ascending orders.
Then put all the code below that sorted array.

Comment: Am sorry but you didn't answer my question... it works fine upto 9 why it didn't bring 9 at first or the others just as 10'th record???

Comment: You are 100% right.
But i don't know how they sort the data.

One thing that i come to know that they group the data like after the items starts with 1 will be group, all the items starts with 2 will be group and so on.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that you can get all the localstorage that way , you need to do some thing like this :

```
for (var key in localStorage){
   console.log(key)
}
```

or

```
for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {
  console.log( localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) ) );
}
```

maybe save the last one after sorting, and then to add more keys.

Comment: I already did that didn't see the code??  for (let i = 0; i < myDatabase.length; i++) {
      lastId = JSON.parse(myDatabase.key(i)).id;
    }